# Ruby on rails-convert activeRecord to arrays

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, rails-activerecord

I currently have a database of compounds.  For each compound, I have a series of data points, each of which consist of a time (t0, t2,t4,...,t24) and a corresponding value. I would like to extract the keys (t0, t2,t4,...,t24) and values and put them into separate arrays so I can graph them.
I obtain my active record with the line:

```
data = Info.where('compoundName = ?',params[:cmpName])
```

Then I attempted to extract the keys and values using the lines:

```
a1 = data.keys
a2 = data.values
```

but I got the error:

> undefined method `keys' for ActiveRecord::Relation::ActiveRecord_Relation_Info:0x007fafcdadba18

I looked this up and saw that the issue was that the sql query returned a data type that could not support these methods.  But I am unsure how unpack the active record into the desired arrays.  If I print out the active record it looks like this:

```
[#<Info num: 6, compoundName: "cmp1", t0: 78.77867, t2: 69.57333, t4: 68.95822, t6: 66.21941, t8: 65.37794, t10: 62.696, t12: 60.85907, t14: 60.40803, t16: 58.97237, t18: 59.55294, t20: 57.79256, t22: 57.17229, t24: 56.31774>]
```

Does anyone know how to accomplish this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to convert the sql object into array, you can simply do this:

```
data = Info.where('compoundName = ?',params[:cmpName]).to_a
```

and it will perform the fetch.

Answer (score 1):

All you have to do is this,

```
data_hash = Info.where('compoundName = ?',params[:cmpName]).first.as_json.select{|v| v=~ /^t[02468]*/}

a1 = data_hash.keys
a2 = data_hash.values
```

As suggested by @suslov ...

Answer (score 0):

So the query is currently returning all records which match on compoundName. If you only want one, you should make the query: `data = Info.where('compoundName = ?',params[:cmpName]).first`

I assume `keys` and `values` are methods on the Info model? Maybe something like models/info.rb:

```
class Info < ActiveRecord::Base
  def keys
    (0..24).map { |n| "t#{n}" }
  end

  def values
    keys.map { |key| self[key] }
  end
end
```

And make sure you're calling those methods on individual Info records.

You should look into storing the data in array form in the database though.

Comment: Sorry I am new to ruby on rails, would I define these methods in info.rb?  I tried doing that but when I try to use the methods it still says that keys and values are undefined methods.

Answer (score 0):

First, I'd rename your "Info" class to "Compound" to make it apparent what you're working with :-)

That said, `Info.where()` is returning *all* records that match, so if there's only one (or you only care about one) then use `Info.where().first`.

If you want to refer to your tN properties as "keys" and "values" then define those methods in your model.

Comment: My database is guaranteed to only have one tuple with the compoundName so I think Info.where() will return just the one record that matches

Comment: It will only find one record that matches, but it will return it in an array. This is a single object: `{}`this is a single object in an array: `[{}]`. Use `.first` as Hassan says to get the former.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`as_json`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveModel/Serializers/JSON/as_json):

```
Info.where(compoundName: params[:cmpName]).as_json
```

So you can use `.keys` and `.values` methods.

Comment: I am trying to make the elements: num, compoundName, t0,t2,t4,....,t24 into keys.  Then I am trying to make the numbers after the colon in the active record the values.  For example, if the active record contains t0:78.77, then t0 is the key and 78.77 is the value

Comment: @adub: Updated.